# Elasticsearch - passing an array as argument in a query

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm trying to do a query in Elasticsearch using an array as argument for the query. For example, I want to search for [apple, orange, pineapple] in the field "fruits". But in my case I want to search for an array of companyIds. I came up with this query:

```
{  
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "must":[  
            {  
               "range":{  
                  "eventconnected":{  
                     "from":"2018-11-21T15:00:00.023Z",
                     "to":"2018-11-22T15:00:00.023Z",
                     "include_lower":true,
                     "include_upper":true,
                     "boost":1.0
                  }
               }
            },
            {  
               "match":{  
                  "idunity":{  
                     "query":[  
                        "157",
                        "160"
                     ],
                     "operator":"OR",
                     "prefix_length":0,
                     "max_expansions":50,
                     "fuzzy_transpositions":true,
                     "lenient":false,
                     "zero_terms_query":"NONE",
                     "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query":true,
                     "boost":1.0
                  }
               }
            }
         ],
         "adjust_pure_negative":true,
         "boost":1.0
      }
   }
}
```

When I run this query, I get the following error:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"[match] unknown token [START_ARRAY] after [query]","line":20,"col":30}],"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"[match] unknown token [START_ARRAY] after [query]","line":20,"col":30},"status":400}
```

It's as if I can't pass an array as argument for the query. So my question is: what is the correct way to pass an array as argument of a query in ElasticSearch?

To give more context: I'm doing this in a java project, the searchSourceBuilder for this query is the following:
locaisTemp is the array I'm trying to pass as an argument.

```
SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
            sourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders
                    .boolQuery()
                        .must(QueryBuilders
                            .rangeQuery("eventconnected")
                                .from(tempDate0.getTime())
                                .to(tempDate.getTime()))
                        .must(QueryBuilders
                                .matchQuery("idunity", locaisTemp)) 
                    );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `termsQuery` instead and also you should use `filter()` instead of `must()` since you're only filtering:

```
                    ...
                    .filter(QueryBuilders
                       ^    .termsQuery("idunity", locaisTemp))
                       |         ^ 
                       |         |
                       change this 
                    ...
```

Comment: I just had time to test this now, it works like a charm, once again you saved my life Val :D
It seems like I need to study more about ElasticSearch because it isn't as straight forward as I thought... so, to search for an array I need to use termsQuery instead of matchQuery? Is there any reason for why the matchQuery doesn't work with arrays?

Comment: I just checked the [documentations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) and it makes much more sense now, thank you Val!

I'll definetly go back to studying more about ES before I go any further into my project.

Comment: The match query works with words in a string, you can use a match query with the  following input string `"157 160"`, but for an array it makes more send to use a terms query.